# Invoking Safari on iOS without opening a new website

Tags: ios, safari

The situation is like this:

1. User opens app from a website using a custom urlscheme
2. User does stuff in the app
3. User clicks button in the app to return to the website in Safari.

I have tried opening a new tab containing a javascript:window.close() but this does not work on iOS 6.1.

So my question is: Is there a way to open Safari to view the website the user left from? Either with a working new tab that closes itself or a different route?

Answer (score 0):

When you open the app with your custom url scheme, pass the actual page url as an argument.

```
mycustomUrlScheme://mydomain.com?objectid=1234&callback_url=encoded_url
```

In your app, handle the url for the content info and keep the page url to open it afterwards. It will make safari open a new tab. But that should be a good start.

Comment: That is a good start indeed, but the callback url should be the same url as the page the app got invoked from. I don't want the same tab or window opened twice.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you can do it.

1. user opens mobile safari for example http://www.example.com
2. user clicks a link that is appscheme://open and the application become active
3. user taps a button to open safari for example http://www.example.com?q=test

for the third step you can use [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url]

Comment: I have thought about this, the problem is that I want the Safari to open the same tab/window, and not a new one. The user should return where he left off, without the need of manually closing a tab or window.

Comment: @Njerpie I have the same issues, did you fix it?